# How to evaluate this limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Can anyone give a hint?
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(\left(x^3+\frac{x}2-\tan \frac1{x}\right)\text{e}^{\frac1{x}}-\sqrt{1+x^6}\right)$$

Comment: What are your (failed?) attempts at finding the limit of this problem?

Comment: *Once again, a question from you with absolutely no context or no thoughts of your own. Despite the fact that you've been asked numerous times to improve your questions.* (This is a quote from a comment on another of your questions.)

Answer (score 3):

$e^{1/x} \to 1+1/x+O(1/x^2)$,
$\sqrt{1+x^6} = x^3\sqrt{1+x^{-6}}
\to x^3(1+x^{-6}/2 + O(x^{-12}))
= x^3 + x^{-3}/2 + O(x^{-9})
$,
and
$\tan(1/x) \to 1/x + O(1/x^2)$.

Combining these,
$\begin{align}
(x^3+x/2-\tan(1/x))e^{1/x}-\sqrt{1+x^6}
&\to (x^3+x/2-1/x+O(1/x^2))(1+1/x+O(1/x^2)) \\
&-(x^3 + x^{-3}/2 + O(x^{-9}))\\
&=x^3+x/2-1/x+O(1/x^2) + x^2+1/2-1/x^2+O(1/x^3)+O(x) \\
&-(x^3 + x^{-3}/2 + O(x^{-9}))\\
&= x^2+x/2+1/2 + O(x) \\
&= x^2+O(x) \\
\end{align}
$

Essentially, the $x^3$ cancel out,
and what is left is primarily the
$x^2$ plus smaller terms
(unless I made a mistake).
The $x/2$ and $\tan(1/x)$ don't seem to matter.

Answer (score 2):

More general hint: expand $\tan\frac{1}{x}$ and $e^{1/x}$ in series at infinity.